# BigQuery: compute entropy of a column

Tags: google-bigquery, entropy

I have a suggestion for the BQ folks: I think it would be very useful if there was a built-in function that would return the entropy of a column.  A column of discrete categories or values would be relatively easy.  Thoughts?  Does this already exist but I didn't find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple solution is below - it computes number of distinct values in the column, and then takes logarithm on base 2 - this gives the number of bits needed to encode all different values, which is the column entropy.

```
SELECT LOG2(COUNT(DISTINCT column)) FROM Table
```

However, this doesn't take into account the fact that different values have different probabilities. Shannon entropy formula is -SUM(P(xi)*log(P(xi)) where P(xi) is probability of value xi. Here is an example how to compute that in BigQuery, Shannon entropy for column `year` in `natality` table:

```
select -sum(p*log2(p)) from (
select ratio_to_report(c) over() p from (
select year, count(*) c from publicdata:samples.natality group by 1))
```

**UPDATE** In case the column variable is not discrete type (i.e. FLOAT), it is possible to discretize the values. Example below shows one approach - first it finds the maximum and minimum values, computes the range, and then puts all the FLOAT values (weight_pound column in natality table) into 100 buckets. After that - problem is reduced to the entropy of INTEGER values.

```
select discrete_weight, count(*) from (
select 
  cast((weight_pounds - min_weight) * 100 / range_weight as integer)
    as discrete_weight 
from [publicdata:samples.natality] a cross join 
(select 
  min(weight_pounds) as min_weight, 
  max(weight_pounds) - min(weight_pounds) as range_weight 
from [publicdata:samples.natality]) b) group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mosha that was very helpful.  It works like a charm _and_ I learned a lot more about BQ in the process!  I haven't tried to work this out on my own yet, but it seems like this idea could probably be extended to continuous-valued columns, maybe by using something like NTILE() or RANK() ?  If someone has already worked this out, it would save me the effort ;-)

Comment: Thanks again, Mosha, very helpful and instructive.

Comment: related - full python example based on this code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780166/parallel-sql-query-in-bigquery-mix-legacy-and-standard-running-on-metadata-sch

Answer (score 0):

in clickhouse

```sql
select splitByString('', col) as s, arrayReduce('entropy', s) as entropy_s from (
select col from t 
)
```