# Is there a way to calculate entropy in sql \ mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to calculate the **entropy** of a list in mysql.
Now I run this and move to python:

```
select group_concat(first_name), last_name
from table
group by last name
```

What I am looking for would be the equivalent of

```
entropy(first_name)
```

Returning a single number for each.
Similar to the below usage for numericals:

`std(age)/avg(age)`

EDIT- Partially answered: Thank you to commenter [@IVO GELOV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5962802/ivo-gelov) for a very efficient approximation:

`SELECT LOG2(COUNT(DISTINCT column)) FROM Table`

Comment: I do hate questions where I have to dig out a dictionary. Also please add sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312734/5962802, https://exchangetuts.com/how-do-i-compute-the-approximate-entropy-of-a-bit-string-1639596608290804

Comment: Hi - you might know what you mean by "entropy" but that doesn't mean that the people likely to see your question (which is tagged with generic SQL tags) do. Please explain, with examples, what you mean and what you are trying to achieve

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on solution above and an approximate of the t-test we reach comparative weighted entropy. Hacky, but works like a charm:

```
CASE
    WHEN count(*)-1 < 6 THEN (1 + LOG2(COUNT(distinct first_name)))*5.61*power(count(*)-1,-0.71)
    WHEN count(*)-1 >= 6 and cnt-1 < 27 THEN (1 + LOG2(COUNT(distinct first_name)))*2.2*power(count(*)-1,-0.081)
    ELSE (1 + LOG2(COUNT(distinct first_name)))*1.815*power(count(*)-1,-0.02)
END as entropy
```

Defined for rows with count(*) > 1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).